# What does Equidimensional equation mean

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, euclidean-geometry

What does the adjective equidimensional mean ?
I encountered it while studying Cauchy-euler equation in differential equations with applications and historical notes by gf simmons :
http://matematicaeducativa.com/foro/download/file.php?id=2247&sid=f867258ad39908e15b331d33e763a8b0

Kindly see page no. 126, q5

Wikipedia says :

"A topological space X is said to be equidimensional if for all points p in X the dimension at p that is, dim p(X) is constant. The Euclidean space is an example of an equidimensional space."

But isn't this always the case and how is an ODE related with dimensions of a point ?

I am a first year undergraduate , please explain in simple or heuristic way.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you elaborate more on the context? Because it seems to me that these "equidimensionalities" have nothing to do with each other, except the name.

Comment: Take the union of the x-axis and the unit disk. There you have points of dimension one and two, thus not "of the same dimension", not equidimensional.

Comment: But isn't x-axis also subset of a two dimensional plane

Comment: Sorru, due to no reputation , i can't upload picture of the concerned pages

Comment: Added the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topological space is called *equi-dimensional*, if every irreducible component of X has the same dimension - see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0054). This is *not* always the case.
The disjoint union of two spaces $X$ and $Y$ (as topological spaces) of different dimension is an example of a non-equidimensional space.

Edit: Now there is a link in the question, which shows that we talk about [Euler's equidimensional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation). So what is the meaning of "equidimensional" for this equation?

Say for example the variable $y$ is a distance measured in meters $(\mbox{m})$ and
the variable $x$ is time, measured in seconds $(\mbox{s})$. Then $y'$ is a velocity
$(\mbox{m/s})$ and $y''$ is an acceleration $(\mbox{m/s}^2)$. Thus $x^2 y''$ is a distance $(\mbox{m})$ and $x y'$ is a distance $(\mbox{m})$. All three terms have the same dimension $(\mbox{m})$. This we call "equidimensional".